# My pseudo-class :not with input element isn't working correctly

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to use the CSS3 `input` pseudo-class, but it's not working. These styles are being applied to my inputs inside the `.import-holder` div. They should apply to everything except the inputs.

```css
.content .import-holder:not(input){
 width: 500px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid white;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container import-holder">
   <form method="POST" action="">
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Import Excel</legend>
         <input name="filename" type="file">
         <input type="submit" value="Import">                
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector applies to non-input elements **with** the class `.import-holder` that are descendants of elements with the class `.content`. If you want to apply styles to all elements inside `div.import-holder` except input elements, this is your selector: `.import-holder *:not(input)`. And btw, `input` is an element selector, not a pseudo class.

Comment: @connexo Now everything inside is receiving those styles, including the last input. What I don't get is: I have 2 inputs but only the last one is getting the styles... The psdeu-class I refer is the `:not`

Comment: Show your HTML. Also, it is competely unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: still unclear what you trying to achieve

Comment: Inside the div, I have 2 inputs and some other elements.  I need to apply the styles to all elements inside `import-holder` except the `input` type

Answer (score 1):

`.content .import-holder:not(input)` will select descendants of elements with a `content` class, that are not `input` elements, and have an `import-holder` class.

You appear to want `.content .import-holder *:not(input)` (note the space!), which looks for elements that are not an input and descendants of `.import-holder` elements.

Here is a simplified example of what the selector works on.

```css
* {
  color: red;
}

.import-holder *:not(input) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="import-holder">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <input type="text" value="Input" />
  <h2>Another heading</h2>
  <p>Paragraph with a <span>span</span> in it.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. Apply the styles to all elements inside `import-holder` except the `input` type. But with your code, the last input only, is getting the styles too.

Comment: I have added an example of how the selector works. It seems to work the way you want it to?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now  I need to figure out why it's not working with me.

Comment: I think you only need to add a space and `*`. if not, I'll be happy to look at a Fiddle for you.

Comment: The rules get applied precisely as you want in your Fiddle. You can check this using developer tools. However, the rules get applied to the `form`, `fieldset` *and* the `legend`, which is probably not what you want. What *do* you want to have happen?

Comment: I want to apply to everything, except those `inputs` inside the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133559/discussion-between-just-a-student-and-playhardgopro).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by specifying the input type element, you want to exclude from styling.

Bellow code will work as your need.

```
.content .import-holder input:not([type='text']):not([type='submit']) {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```